# Container-fluid with two columns. Right side needs to be confined

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See this question: [Bootstrap - Container-fluid with two columns. Right side needs to be confined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800338/bootstrap-container-fluid-with-two-columns-right-side-needs-to-be-confined/52644131?noredirect=1#comment92221786_52644131)

How would @Rustyjim's solution work if I want the left side to be confined and the right side fluid?

Comment: Ok, will do, sorry I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those interested, I ended up applying this class to a fluid container and this is working. My container is 1200px wide.

```
.fluid-left {
margin-left: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
}
```